# Track files with Git LFS in SourceTree

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree, git-lfs

I am following [this](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-lfs) guide about how to use Git LFS.

The article states that users need to have the Git LFS command-line client installed, or a Git LFS aware GUI client such as Sourcetree.

Much as it seems simple, I can't find any information on how to track files with Git LFS in SourceTree GUI, only command line instructions like git lfs track "*.ogg". Is it possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally, found the solution myself:

Go to **Tools** -> **Options** -> **Git** and press **Update Embedded**

Tick **Enable the Bitbucket LFS Media Adapter**

Go to **Repository** -> **Git LFS** -> **Initialize Repository**

Go to **Repository** -> **Git LFS** -> **Track / untrack files ...** and add the extensions to be stored in LFS.

Answer (score 1):

In Mac, it is different than what the accepted answer says.

See following link:

[Using Embedded Git Or System Git in Sourcetree](https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/using-embedded-git-or-system-git-in-sourcetree-785323587.html)

Answer (score 0):

I also found using LFS in Sourcetree confusing. Then I found this menu that helped quite a bit.

[image]